# Install second mysql

Tags: mysql, multiple-instances

I have a VM that has mysql 5.5.40 installed in it. And now i want to install mysql 5.6 without updating or replacing existing version. Means i want to use these two side by side.

1. I have tried to install with `apt-get install mysql-server-5.6` but it was replaced/upgraded the existing one.
2. Also tried it with the deb file result was same as above.
3. Last i used compressed tar file. But couldn't run it. I tried it with `mysqld_multi` tool. Also tried with separated my.cnf, datadir, lock and pid. It fails on pid when i try to run it.

Did i miss something with these 3 options?

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Could you tell why you want to do this? Maybe there is another, better way for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compile mysql 5.6 from source with ./configure --prefix=/opt/mysql56
make
make install
 if it still uses autoconf.
You would also have to change the port number.

But i think it would be much easier to have mysql 5.6 in a separate virtual machine, using virt-manager (kvm), vmware ore virtualbox.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. VM was the easiest solution.